# Get last added element of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pivot element and I want that whenever an element is added to this pivot element a javascript function is called on it. The call must happen exact once per element.

`DOMNodeInserted` is marked as deprecated so I tried to use the workaround found [here](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/). The approach is working fine, but in addition to the element to which the addition happended (`event.target`), I also need to know which element was added.

Do I have to keep record of all elements added to my pivot element and then compare them after the event happened to detect new elements or is there an easier approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variable references a node, to retrieve the last item added to it you can use the lastChild property.

```
var node = document.getElementById("something");
var last = node.lastChild;

last.appendChild(document.createTextNode("I'm the last one..."));
```

An alternative may be childNodes:

```
var node = document.getElementById("something");

node.childNodes[node.childNodes.length - 1].appendChild(document.createTextNode("I'm the last one..."));
```

For extra reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes